# Editing Pop Up message in Siebel

Tags: siebel

I need help on Editing the Pop up Message that comes from Siebel while trying to download and attachment. Have done lots of research but cant figure it yet.
It looks like a Joption Pane show message dialog in Java. The image is attached within.

Am also guessing its a business service method (GetFile Method) and its hard coded or in a class property.
the File download pop up message needs to be edited. Kindly find the Image attached within.

Any help on how the attachment drill-down link works would also be appreciated so it can help my research further.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message itself is stored in the core.cat file under BIN\ENU in the Siebel folder. If you wish to change the message to new one for all users , then you can modify this .cat file. I'm not sure of dynamically changing, maybe possible via javascript.

Comment: Hello Ranjith I have modified this file using notepad++ but the Siebel application wont start on my local, when I use the original core.cat the application then starts..I cant try this on production server.

Comment: How do I edit the core.cat file properly or do I suggest we ask oracle for a new core.cat with the suggested changes , because I actually saw the message in the core.cat file but after editing ..the system wont start up until I used the unchanged core.cat.  Thanks ranjith you have helped a lot wont mind your email address.  Regards

Comment: @lawal, Oracle does not recomment modifying these files. But if you open them in a hex editor and type over the text, keeping the filesize the same, the new message will appear. I have tried this earlier and it worked then.  There are already bug/enhancement requests raised for a way to modify these messages, but so far there is no Oracle supplied solution.